# Как завершить процесс "ng test" запущенный в pipeline Jenkins

Tags: node.js, angular, jenkins-pipeline, karma

В pipeline Jenkins я запускаю тесты приложения на Angular командой

```
ng test
```

Мне нужно, чтобы после тогда как они выполнились успешно процесс завершил свою работу, а после этого и текущий stage тоже завершился и запустился следующий.
Но когда я запускаю эту команду процесс остается висеть до бесконечности ожидая изменений в коде.
Я попробовал запускать вот с такими параметрами

```
ng test --wath=false --poll=500
```

Если я запускаю эту команду в терминале, то все прекрасно - процесс завершается и появляется доступ к командной строке.
Но если я зупускаю его в pipeline Jenkins, то он все равно продолжает висеть.
В чем тут проблема?
Как мне заставить его завершиться?